# Powershell script to find and replace words based on asset tag input

Tags: powershell

Can someone please help me modify this script to generate and modify the document faster? It currently takes about 5-10 seconds to create the variables. About 10 seconds for the entire script to run.

Here is the code for the script:

## Copy Word Template to Local C Drive:

```
Copy-Item \\172.16.0.75\allaccess\Scripts\transfer2.docx C:\
```

## Create Replace-Word Function:

```
function Replace-Word(
    [string]$Document,
    [string]$FindText,
    [string]$ReplaceText
) {
    $ReplaceAll = 2
    $FindContinue = 1

    $MatchCase = $false
    $MatchWholeWord = $true
    $MatchWildcards = $false
    $MatchSoundsLike = $false
    $MatchAllWordForms = $false
    $Forward = $true
    $Wrap = $FindContinue
    $Format = $false

    $Word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
    $Word.Visible = $false

    $OpenDoc = $Word.Documents.Open($Document)
    $Selection = $Word.Selection

    $Selection.Find.Execute(
        $FindText,
        $MatchCase,
        $MatchWholeWord,
        $MatchWildcards,
        $MatchSoundsLike,
        $MatchAllWordForms,
        $Forward,
        $Wrap,
        $Format,
        $ReplaceText,
        $ReplaceAll
    ) | Out-Null

    $OpenDoc.Close()
    $Word.Quit()
}

#Prompt user for information and generate several variables: 

    $assettag = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input Asset Tag'
    $fullasset = id              : 3973
    name              : XTX-L-25677
    asset_tag         : 25677
    serial            : XXXXXX
    model             : @{id=1440; name=Dell Latitude 5591}
    model_number      :
    eol               : @{date=2018-08-06; formatted=Aug 6, 2018}
    status_label      : @{id=6; name=Deployed; status_type=deployable; status_meta=deployed}
    category          : @{id=1; name=Laptop}
    manufacturer      : @{id=1; name=Dell}
    supplier          : @{id=6; name=Dell}
    notes             :
    order_number      :
    company           : @{id=2; name=SITE}
    location          :
    rtd_location      : @{id=287; name= Technology Division}
    image             :
    assigned_to       : @{id=2672; username=first; name=first last; first_name=First; last_name=last;
    warranty_months   :
    warranty_expires  :
    created_at        : @{datetime=2018-08-14 09:41:00; formatted=Aug 14, 2018 9:41AM}
    updated_at        : @{datetime=2019-06-11 10:23:38; formatted=Jun 11, 2019 10:23AM}
    last_audit_date   :
    next_audit_date   :
    deleted_at        :
    purchase_date     : @{date=2018-08-06; formatted=Aug 6, 2018}
    last_checkout     : @{datetime=2019-06-10 08:40:22; formatted=Jun 10, 2019 8:40AM}
    expected_checkin  :
    purchase_cost     :
    checkin_counter   : 2
    checkout_counter  : 3
    requests_counter  : 0
    user_can_checkout : False
    custom_fields     : @{User=; Computer Type=; OS=; Memory=; Processor=; Wired MAC=; Wireless MAC=}
    available_actions : @{checkout=True; checkin=True; clone=True; restore=False; update=True; delete=True}

foreach ($fullasset in $fullasset)
{
    $model = (($fullasset).model).name
    $serial = ($fullasset).serial
    $location = (($fullasset).rtd_location).name
    $category = (($fullasset).category).name
    $status = (($fullasset).status_label).name
}

    $date = Get-Date -Format "M-dd-yy"
    $dom = $env:userdomain
    $usr = $env:username
    $name = ([ADSI]"WinNT://$dom/$usr,user").FullName
```

## Use generated variables and Replace-Word function to modify document:

```
Replace-Word -Document C:\transfer2.docx -FindText '$assettag' -ReplaceText $assettag
Replace-Word -Document C:\transfer2.docx -FindText '$model' -ReplaceText $model
Replace-Word -Document C:\transfer2.docx -FindText '$location' -ReplaceText $location
Replace-Word -Document C:\transfer2.docx -FindText '$date' -ReplaceText $date
Replace-Word -Document C:\transfer2.docx -FindText '$serial' -ReplaceText $serial
Replace-Word -Document C:\transfer2.docx -FindText '$x' -ReplaceText $x
Replace-Word -Document C:\transfer2.docx -FindText '$status' -ReplaceText $status
Replace-Word -Document C:\transfer2.docx -FindText '$category' -ReplaceText $category
Replace-Word -Document C:\transfer2.docx -FindText '$name' -ReplaceText $name
```

Please let me know if there is anything I can consolidate or modify to improve speed.

Comment: I modified some parts of the script for speed. Does anyone have recommendations on how to improve the replace-word function?